# deconvolution in frequncy vs in time for sparse \ smooth signals

Tags: noise, deconvolution, sparse-model

I have a noisy signal $f(t)$ that is measured in time, and I am interested in estimating it's power spectrum, or frequency content. The signal has an impulse response so it can be described as a sum of these impulses $f(t)=\sum \alpha_i I(t_i)$, where $I$ can be a sinc function or a Ricker wavelet or something I can in principle measure.  Now, I can either deconvolve in time or in frequency to obtain the frequency content using $L1$ or $L2$ norm minimization , and if there is infinite sampling and no noise the answer is the same. However, there is time dependent noise, and also a finite measuring time (or it is always a bandwidth-limited signal).
I am not sure what is preferred for the case the signal is sparse in frequency, or when it is not.
This question is a bit general, and may have an "it depends" answer, and I am interested in the details.

Comment: I presume that $$f(t)=\sum \alpha_i I(t_i)$$ is a summation over $i$.  Then this appears to add to something that is not a function of $t$.  Can you be more explicit, where the variable $t$ is visible on the right-hand side? Could it be $$f(t)=\sum_i \alpha_i I(t-t_i)$$ ?

Comment: Can you also show by example what exactly you are doing when you process the signal as a deconvolution in time or frequency?  Signals don’t have an impulse response, but systems do. The signal measured is the result of a source signal passed through a system with a given impulse response. I am familiar with deconvolution techniques to estimate the system’s impulse response or the source waveform but would like to see how you are applying it to get the PSD to better understand your question / goals (vs Welch or other methods)